# mysql query, selecting a certain array of results

Tags: php, mysql

We have a list of IDs, for example:

```
11, 22, 55, 99, 187
```

We have a table with a field "id".

We basically want to select ALL results where the `id` equals `11, 22, 55, 99, 187`

What would be the best way to do a mySQL query like this?

Instead of doing `WHERE`id`= '11' OR '22'.....`

We are using this with PHP, as we have a list of IDs and are wanting to select the results using these IDs with a mysql query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
Where id IN (11,22,55,99,187)
```

Answer (score 1):

try IN clause

[Mysql IN clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned on other answers you can use the `IN (...)` clause. But if you have a long list of id values and you want the best performance, then I would suggest using a temporary table to store the values and then use an `INNER JOIN` on the temporary table:

```
/* Create the temporary table */
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_lookup (id INT NOT NULL);
/* Insert values in temp table */
INSERT INTO temp_lookup (id) VALUES (11), (22), (55), (99), (187), ...;
/* Select using INNER JOIN */
SELECT mt.field_list
FROM main_table AS mt INNER JOIN temp_lookup AS tt ON mt.id = tt.id
```

Comment: Did you actually test this or do you have some references? What is the gain? I run a very limited test (4 lookup values/160k records) and saw no gain, actually saw worse performance - 0.12s vs 0.20s. After this I made another test with 33 distinct values in temp_lookup - the difference when to 0.62 for join/temp vs 0.12 with IN. I see no evidence (nor logic) that temp table would work faster. (both test run with no index on id, with indexes both approaches run in 0.0s; with exception that temp table one needs 0.03s to create the temp table)

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql's [IN-function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

Something like:

```
SELECT id from table where id IN (11, 22, 55, 99, 187);
```

It's really logic, just read the manual.