# MySQL, quickest way to select on a phrase as separate words?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

This is my current query

```
WHERE Keywords.Word = '$search'
```

But this only works if `$search` is one word, if its two or three words then it won't find anything as my keywords table words field only has one word per record.

Whats the quickest way to do this ?

Comment: The `$` indicates you're interpolating values directly into your SQL statement. Your code could be vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html), which is a very serious [security risk](http://bobby-tables.com/). The best way of preventing injection is to use prepared statements (though they only help with injections via simple values; other parts of statements, such as table and column names, and compound values generally still need to be interpolated), which your database access provider should support. If it doesn't, you're using an outdated DA provider.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm using `$search = mysql_real_escape_string($search);` which I hope is good enough

Comment: escaping will work, but it's easy to forget, which isn't an issue with prepared statements. In addition, prepared statements are more performant if you're executing the same query multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your programming language, split the search term into an array, and use the `IN` clause :

```
WHERE Keywords.Word IN ('$search[0]','$search[1]',...)
```

Comment: Hmmm, I'm puzzled, I would have thought that it would match the first work then others. The first word I used was unique in the database and the second was a very popular word. It hasn't shown a result for the first work. Is there anything I can do to improve on this ?

Answer (score 0):

`IN` clause will not give you the best performance. You can look at [my answer on this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295738/mysql-query-selecting-a-certain-array-of-results/5295852#5295852).

Answer (score 0):

I would create virtual table based on the search condition, on join against the tables column.

Something like

```
SELECT *
FROM   table t 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'term1' AS name 
             UNION 
             SELECT 'term2' AS name 
             UNION 
             SELECT 'term3' AS name)  f
         ON f.name = w.Word 
WHERE  (f.name IS NOT NULL)
GROUP by t.id
```

In this case you would dynamically construct the virtual table values as static hardcoded values (term1,2,3), and you need to add indexes on the following columns

1. (Word)
2. assuming you have primary key `id`

Comment: What is `w`? And what is `f`?